# Running into a server action looking for data I am not asking it to (Prisma / MongoDB / Next14)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, prisma, server-action

I recently started using Next14, much like everyone else I would assume, and I am running into an error when trying to create a very simple object to push to my 'Decision' collection in the db.  My server action clearly isn't looking for an id argument in the codebase, because it should be auto generated on the server's end with the @map() function in the Prisma Schema.

I am using:
Next 14.0.1
Prisma 5.5.2
Shadcn UI

This is the error I am getting on form submission:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW7Ol.jpg)

This is my schema:

```
model Pros {
  id         String    @id @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt  DateTime  @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  title      String
  weight     Int
  decision   Decision? @relation(fields: [decisionId], references: [id])
  decisionId String    @map("decision")
}

model Cons {
  id         String    @id @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt  DateTime  @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt  DateTime  @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  title      String
  weight     Int
  decision   Decision? @relation(fields: [decisionId], references: [id])
  decisionId String?   @map("decision")
}

model Decision {
  id        String   @id @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  title     String
  pros      Pros[]
  Cons      Cons[]
}
```

this is my server action:

```
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma"

export const addDecision = async (formData) => {

  await prisma.decision.create({
    data: {
      title: formData.get("title"),
    },
  })
}
```

And finally, this is the UI for the form:

```
'use client'
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog"
import { addDecision } from "@/lib/actions"

export default function AddDecision({ children }) {
  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger>Open</DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Are you sure absolutely sure?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            <form action={addDecision}>
              <input name="title" placeholder="title" />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

I've tried:
1.) removing @map from the id in schema (Prisma hated that)
2.) adding const { title } = formData; right above the server action
3.) Pulling my non-existent hair out

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I will be very grateful.

Thanks!